# NHibernate One-To-Many with Joined Subclass

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Never asked a question here before, I'll try to lay this out as succinctly as possible.

I've got a Recipe class, that contains lists of three different types of Ingredient Uses.  These classes all inherit from the base, IngredientUse.  So the mapping looks like this:

```
  <class name="IngredientUse" table="IngredientUses">
    <id name="Id" type="Int64" column="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <!--some other properties-->
    <property name="RecipeId" column="RecipeId"/>
    <joined-subclass name="AdditionUse" table="AdditionUses">
      <key column="Id" foreign-key="FK_AdditionUses_IngredientUses"/>
      <many-to-one name="AdditionUsed" column="AdditionUsed" class="Addition" foreign-key="FK_AdditionUses_Additions"/>
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
```

The one causing problems here is the RecipeId.  From the recipe, I have three separate lists of uses for different ingredient types, defined like so:

```
<bag name="AdditionsUsed" cascade="all" lazy="false">
  <key column="RecipeId"/>
  <one-to-many class="AdditionUse"/>
</bag>
```

Now, I'm running into problems trying to load these lists.  It has something to do with the inheritance.  When I look at the SQL Generated, I see this:

```
SELECT additionsused0_.RecipeId as RecipeId1_
--other columns not really important
FROM AdditionUses additionsused0_ 
inner join IngredientUses additionsused0_1_ 
on additionsused0_.Id=additionsused0_1_.Id 
WHERE additionsused0_.RecipeId=@p0; @p0 = '11'
```

Notice that its' looking for the RecipeId in the subclass' table, and not the base table where the column is actually contained.  I know I could just define a separate table for each ingredient type, but that will cause me problems because there are some situations (ie pricing) where I don't need the additional columns in the subclass table, and would like to be able to load all the ingredients into the same list at once.

I'm certain I must be missing something here, figured someone more familiar with NHibernate on this site might recognize it right off the bat.

Thanks in advance.

**edit:** in case I wasn't clear about what I'm trying to do, this diagram might help (excuse my shoddy UML, hope it doesn't muddy the waters).  There is also an Ingredient base class, and the same subtypes off of that.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior, the key tag is the name of the column in the "many" side that references to the "one"...

Create the tables in a paper, and you'll see that if you want that your ingredient has many additions, you will need add a column in the additions table.

By the way, never map your ids directly, map the entity instead using a many-to-one

Comment: thats the thing, I don't want to map to the AdditionUse table, I want to map to the IngredientUse table, using AdditionUse as a filter and for extra info.  I guess I'll need to abandon NHibernate, or rethink how my tables are set up.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: No, NH must work fine, you aren't working with a complex domain model. You should start over designing your objects, not your tables.
Not sure if I understand all you want to do, but start removing the  <property name="RecipeId"> and the changing the class in the bag to "IngredientUse".

Comment: Maybe I'm just being thick, but I don't think that will get me where I want to go.  The subclasses from I.Use all have their own special data and behavior, and if I change bag type to I.Use, I lose all that.  Seems like a big sacrifice to make to me, when I could easily suck it up and write the SQL.

Comment: I added an image to make sure we're on the same page with regard to what I'm trying to do with the classes.  I'm not 100% sold on it yet, but think it really would work well for my application (the base "IngredientUse" type is used for other things besides recipes, like pricing and scheduling)

Comment: Diego, I had an idea when I was driving around today thinking about what you said, that I think will solve this problem.  A little more mapping, but it'd let me eliminate one table.  I will test it out when I get a chance.  Thanks again!